# Why anonymous method can be pass to a delegator's constructor?

Tags: c#, delegates

```
Action<int, string> s = new Action<int, string>(delegate(int a,string b){});
Action<int, string> ss = delegate(int a, string b) { };
```

Why these both work? Why the constructor Action  can  accept both function and 
delegator?

Comment: Because functions are delegates?

Comment: Because it does support creating delegates from anonymous functions as well as "normal" methods.

Answer (score 4):

You're not *really* making a constructor call in the normal way, even though that's what it looks like.

Instead, this is a *delegate-creation-expression* as described in the C# 5 specification, section 7.6.10.5:

> A *delegate-creation-expression* is used to create a new instance of a *delegate-type*.
>
> ```
> delegate-creation-expression:
>     new   delegate-type   (   expression   )
> ```
>
> The argument of a delegate creation expression must be a method group, an anonymous function or a value of either the compile time type dynamic or a delegate-type.

It's almost always simpler to use the implicit conversion from an anonymous function (lambda expression or anonymous method) to a compatible delegate type, which is what your second line does.

If you remember back to C# 1, this was how we *had* to create delegate instances, although using method groups:

```
Action action = new Action(SomeMethod);
```

C# 2 introduced anonymous methods and also the implicit conversion from method groups to delegates:

```
Action action = SomeMethod;
```

These days, delegate creation expressions are relatively rare because there are more compact ways of doing the same thing.

Note that in some cases - if you're passing the anonymous function or method group as an argument for a parameter of type `Delegate`, for example - you can just cast instead of using a delegate creation expression:

```
Foo((Action<int, string>) delegate(int a, string b) {});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first line you explicitly create the `Action<int, string>` delegate to the anonnymous method. In the second - implicitly.